# How to select last active window across workspaces? [16.04 LTS]

Tags: window-manager

I use workspaces with a great deal of windows! I have a problem:

1. Be using a firefox tab, or terminal window.
2. Change to password manager (on other workspace) by clicking launcher icon
3. Copy password
4. I want to go back to last opened window <- !! **MY PROBLEM** !! how can I do this?

I get 'stuck' at step 4 and go crazy trying to find where I last was. I hate this ! It breaks up my flow. I feel like using my birthday as password for everything ^^

I searched a lot and found advice 
Tapping <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>
but this cannot go across workspaces.

I would love a key that is 'go to last active window' *wherever it may be, changing workspace if needed*

Comment: Hi David thank you that solved it. That is a clever way of looking at it